# Why is in kotlin toDoubleOrNull() much slower than toDouble(). What would be the fastest double parsing method?

Tags: performance, kotlin, double, text-parsing

I have large CSV file that consists only double numbers. What would be the fastest way to parse it? Since I want empty characters or errors to become null values, I started using toDoubleOrNull() and it seriously slowed down loading times.
Switched back to toDouble() with catching NumberFormatException and  assigning null in that case and is again quite faster.
Is there any faster way ( or library ) since I need better performance?

Comment: Why is `toDoubleOrNull` slower is a good question, but "is there any faster way" really depends on the specific CSV file, and the computer you are running this on. I would suggest that you [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: In any case, I'm guessing you are running on the JVM?

Comment: Ohh, interesting. Sounds like someone in Kotlin team tried to optimize too much ;-) Generally speaking, throwing and catching is relatively slow and usually should be avoided for a normal, non-exceptional code flow. I guess this is the reason why `toDoubleOrNull()` uses regular expression to check the value before parsing. It could increase the performance of failures, but... it adds an overhead to success path. I imagine in cases when values are mostly correct, this optimization may actually degrade the performance. But this is only a guess, I don't know for sure this is the reason.

Comment: I did some quick tests and I was not able to measure any differences between .toDouble() and .toDoubleOrNull(). I tested with a list of 100 million random doubles converted to strings, once with 0%, and then with 10%, 25%, and 50% of randomly assigned entries being strings not parseable to doubles.

Comment: I am testing it with 1 000 000 random string numbers and it is more than 10 times slower. Both on the emulator and on the Samsung tablet. Well, I will just stick to ToDouble and my problem is solved.

Comment: Much faster double parsing here: https://github.com/bourgesl/jnumbers